What are the strongest arguments to reject a physicalist reduction of mathematics and logic?
This is a follow-up to Under physicalism, what is the ontological status of the laws of logic, and what is their relationship to the laws of physics? and How does physicalism interpret mathematical theorems in physicalist terms?
If physicalism is true, mathematics and logic exist only as ideas in human brains (or in any other physical mediums we have used to store them). These ideas can be causally explained as patterns inferred from studying and observing reality. Since physicalism posits that reality is ultimately governed by physics, everything would, in principle, be empirical and physical. To be honest, this perspective seems quite coherent, but I would like to hear the strongest philosophical arguments against it.
What are the strongest arguments to reject a physicalist reduction of mathematics and logic? If mathematics and logic are not reducible to physics, as physicalism suggests, where/how else would they "exist," ontologically speaking?

Platonism

To start, even if physicalism is true, that doesn't make everything empirical.
If Physicalism holds, then it presumably holds Beyond the Observable Universe, but there is nothing empirical about anything beyond the Observable Universe.
Similarly, the inside of a black hole, or peering to before cosmological inflation, - may be, even in principle- beyond the scope of
empirical observation, and still be an entirely a physical phenomenon.
It's also not clear that certain quantum phenomenon are observable, as observing perterbs the phenomenon itself.
Onto the topic at hand.
My refutation is as follows ( it is a argument for Platonism)
There is a conflation of the idea of a mathematical object, and the object itself.
It is easy to see how humans constructed the natural numbers, ( as an idea) by looking at patterns in reality. However, our idea of a natural number is not a natural number.
For example, every educated child has an idea of a square, which is clearly inspired by nature.  However, nobody conceives of a square as the actual mathematical object, since squares are 2-dimensional, contain infinitely many points, and are formed for segements which are infinitely thin.
None of which, are possible for humans to imagine. So, mathematics cannot be reduced to physicalism, as, the objects of mathematics- are not objects of our thought. Our thoughts, merely create a apporixamte of the object.
I am arguing that, the idea of a square, does not exist in the mind of any human. What we call a square, in our minds is not a square. Thus, the physicalality of the thought ( chemicals in the brain) - are not a reduction of mathematics to empiricism.
We cannot deduce the properties of a square, by looking at a minds approximation of a square.
However, perhaps a suffiiently capable kind could actually conceive of a legitimate square ( with all its mathematical properties)
So, I ask you to consider a more
complicated object of your choice. A hyperplane, a large cardinal, a polygon with a trillion vertices.
Can these objects exist in our minds? Sure, I can define them, but I cannot conjure them up as an idea. My best attempts create mere shadows.
Even a arbitrarily strong computer, cannot compute the decimal expansion of π. No, computer can, even if we combine them all into a single computer. So, in what sense can I say that π "exists" as an idea? There is no code that a computer can run that fully captures π as a why should any sequence of chemicals in the brain, capture π?
Is describing/defining an object the same as aprehending the object? Surely, the definition of a square is itself not a square. So, the fact that we can define an idea, does not require us to conceive of the object we are defining.
And so, what are these objects, that cannot exist in reality, Cannot exist in our thoughts. But, their study is so fruitful? What is their ontology?
That is, of course Plato's World of Forms.

Follow-up question: If the Platonic world exists how would we know?

I would suspect that it's not possible, under any current epistemology. If it's possible, it would be under some new kind of logic/framework of knowledge. I'm not even sure what "exists" means, in the Platonic Context.

When it comes to mathematics, I have the belief that certain theories ( if consistent) are consistent because they are true. I take their Consistency as a Platonic Reality, in the sense that via Gödel, their consistency is not showable via proof ( i.e. via empirical fact). So, I take the [perhaps radical] position that consistent theories are in the domain of Platonic Truth

Or rather, the Consistency of the Theory, is in the Realm of Platonic Truth

A refutation of physicalism and an argument for Platonism are not quite the same thing. A physicalist may just reject the existence of abstract objects, beyond our thoughts of such objects. Kinda like unicorns don't exist, but we can still imagine them. You made the point that abstract objects are distinct from thoughts of abstract objects, which a physicalist could trivially accept. You didn't really present any argument for why we should think abstract objects exist, or what that even means.

"None of which, are possible for humans to imagine" - I don't know about you, but I'm picturing a square in my mind right now that's 2-dimensional and which arguably contains infinitely many points (because any shape except single points contains infinitely many points). Whether the edges are infinitely thin are debatable. Why do you say that's impossible to imagine?

I am happy to concede that point. I say it, because I suspect that the "arguably contains infinitely many points, and edges are infinitely thin" - is a difficult position to defend. However, my overall post works just fine if you replace a square with a n-th dimensional cube of sufficiently high dimensions. Furthermore, that's just for spatial dimensions. A proper square, is unitless. So the points could be spatial, time, or any other unit. Can humans imagine a square where the sides aren't spatial?

@NotThatGuy I don't have an argument for the existence of Platonic Objects. I don't even have a definition for their existence. The strongest argument for their "existence" that I have ever heard  is that we have no other explanation for the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics in physics. There is also the phenomenon of the consistency of theories, which is entirely beyond the scope of mathematics to explain via proof. So, why would a theorie be consistent? One explanation, is that they are real.

@MichaelCarey "my overall post works just fine if you replace a square with a n-th dimensional cube" - if part of your argument for why maths objects exist Platonically is that we can't imagine them, but we can imagine at least one, then the argument doesn't seem to work. Unless you concede that some maths objects might not have a Platonic existence, that is. But that would give us less reason to think any maths object has a Platonic existence. Because then we'd need some differentiating criteria, and the limits of our imagination doesn't seem like a categorical distinction of existence.

"we have no other explanation for the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics in physics" + "why would a theory be consistent" - (a) there are consistent patterns in how physics works, and (b) evolution helped us identify those patterns - the organisms that thought 1+1=3 had a much harder time surviving in a world which doesn't align with that idea. I don't know how calling maths "real" helps to explain that, or what that would even mean. If maths has some concrete existence, now you introduce the problems of how and where that exists, and how that connects to physics and to our brains.

That doesn't explain why the patterns are ( so far) best( most accuratley) described using mathematics. Basically, why does it seem like so many objects behave as if they were mathematical objects. If they arent mathematical objects?

@NotThatGuy Possible theistic-Platonic solution: math exists as ideas in God's mind, and math is effective in physics because God used math to design the universe. Of course, this begs the question of how do we know that God exists in the first place [insert endless debates...]

@MichaelCarey Relevant: Mathematical universe hypothesis

@MichaelCarey "why the patterns are (so far) best (most accurately) described using mathematics" - I can only presume you imagine the patterns and maths both already existed, and needed to fit into one another in just the right way. That is not at all what the physicalist view is. If anything, that seems more like a problem for Platonism. For physicalism, the maths we developed describes the patterns well because that's precisely what we developed the maths to do. We rejected maths that didn't fit the patterns. "behave as if they were mathematical objects" - I don't know what that means.

@NotThatGuy that's ahistorical. We didnt develop math to follow patterns that decribe the physical world. That's not the mathematical approach at all. From the Complex Numbers, to Axioms of Infinity, to the Real Line- It's not clear any of it , is derived from patterns in the real world. The maths, it is very often, are developed- significantly before any kind of pattern fitting, to the real world is found. And, many times, no pattern is found at all.

@MichaelCarey If you want to accuse people of lying, you've gotta do a better job than you did at backing up that accusation. You say maths describes reality so extremely well. I say it was developed to do that. You reply that actually maths does an abysmal job of describing reality. Huh? "many times, no pattern is found at all" - literally supporting my point. Complex numbers, to pick one example, is merely a logical extension of things that do describe reality - square roots and negative numbers. Certainly nowhere close to a good example of maths developed with no connection to reality.


If mathematics and logic are not reducible to physics, as physicalism suggests, where else would they "exist," ontologically speaking?

For a non-physicalist conception of existence, there is no "where", since that is a physical concept.
See generally, platonism.

Question slightly edited. Sorry if it invalidates your answer.

By the way, I'm curious. When you argued earlier for the existence of a priori mathematical/logical knowledge, this didn't make sense to me under physicalism. So, just to confirm, are you a Platonist?

Physicalism is compatible with having a priori truths. Accepting priori truths does not imply a platonist view (that those truths are true because they reflect some independent "reality" existing next to physical reality, independent of thought). The concept of "a priori truth" vs "a posteriori" is an epistemic concept (-> how we know sth). Physicalism is metaphysical claim about what exists. "What empirically exists" and "what is real/true" do not have to be treated as equivalent concepts in physicalism.

@mudskipper Would you like to post an answer to Do physicalists think a priori knowledge exists?

@user80226 - Thanks - I will consider doing so.

@Lowri  - You and others have pointed to platonism as possible refutation. But I assume you yourself are not a platonist - right? (@user80226's question is valid, I think). I'm also not a platonist. But I believe both "platonism" and "anti-platonism" (especially treating math as mere formalism) are belief traps (as the mathematician Gabriel Stolzenberg has called them). "Platonism" may just be a more pernicious one.


If physicalism is true, mathematics and logic exist only as ideas in human brains (or in any other physical mediums we have used to store them). These ideas can be causally explained as patterns inferred from studying and observing reality. Since physicalism posits that reality is ultimately governed by physics, everything would, in principle, be empirical and physical.

I would broadly agree with that, to the exception of existence itself (or reality, if you prefer). Physicalism doesn't and could not possibly explain why any reality exists, and why reality is what it is. This also includes the problem of the existence of consciousness.

To be honest, this perspective seems quite coherent, but I would like to hear the strongest philosophical arguments against it.

If physicalism is true, then the status of every particular science and of science in general is the same as the status of formal logic and mathematics.
Since physicalism posits that reality is ultimately governed by physics, everything would, in principle, be empirical and physical, including physicalism itself.
Are physicalist ideas causally explained as patterns inferred from studying and observing reality?
We have the same problem with logic. Illogical ideas are crap, and logical ideas are all . . . logical. It follows logically that we can explain everything we think which is logical (and therefore not crap) by somehow applying logic to our observation of reality; including, therefore, physicalism and physics. Who needs physicalism?

What are the strongest arguments to reject a physicalist reduction of mathematics and logic?

We don't need to reject physicalism. We only need to see that it follows from our logical capacity, our other cognitive capacities such as perception and memory, as well as our naïve, unshakable and ultimately unprovable belief that we see reality itself with our own eyes.

If mathematics and logic are not reducible to physics, as physicalism suggests, where/how else would they "exist," ontologically speaking?

Mathematics and formal logic are reducible to physics only in principle. No one is able to actually do it, not yet at any rate.
Logic is a cognitive capacity which comes with any animal brain and is therefore the result of natural selection, and so ultimately of the physical world.
